# Validate if person is present or not

Tags: python, validation, while-loop

I have done this code in python and using a while loop my task is to :
After sorting the names the user should be able to validate if someone is present by entering his name

```
names = []
while True:
    newName = input("Enter name: ").title()
    if newName == "Sort":
      names.sort()
      print ("List sorted by names: " + str(names))
      break

    names.append(newName)
    print ("Names are: ", names)
```

Comment: Using a while-loop and not a for-loop, write a program that:

1)Allow the user to enter any number of guest names (one at a time).

2) Whenever the user writes “sort” the program should output the list sorted by name.

3) Once sorted the user should be able to validate if someone is present by entering his name

Comment: This is my task and i have done the first two points of it but i struggle with the third

Comment: To check if a name is in a list you only need `if newName in names`.  This is True if newName is in the list, False if not.  Not sure why sorting was needed, except to make the display of names better.  Check out: [Python Membership and Identity Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-membership-identity-operators-not-not/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of posted code to perform the three tasks

1. Allow the user to enter any number of guest names (one at a time).
2. Display entered names in sorted order
3. Let users enter names to check if the name is on the list

**Code**

```
# Task 1. Enter names of guests
names = []
while True:
    newName = input("Enter name to add to list: ").title()

    if newName == "Sort":
        # Task 2. Display list of names in sorted order
        names.sort()
        print (f"List sorted by names: {names}")
        break
        
    names.append(newName)
    
# Task 3. Let user enter names to check if name is on list
while True:
    newName = input("Enter name to check if on list: ").title()
    if not newName:
        break     # Enters blank line to end checking
        
    if newName in names:
        print(f'{newName} is in list')
    else:
        print(f'{newName} is not in list')
```